# Load multiple images from local directory using a filename

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I am writing a simple website which loads multiple images in a local directory using a txt file containing [all of these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxBm7.png) the images' names.

The flow is that the website reads the txt file for images' names (i.e. 1.jpg) then loads the images with the corresponding names to the website.

I am currently stuck at this. Any suggestion is welcome :)

**UPDATE 1**

My apologies. I have successfully read the input file line by line. Although, I have not figured out how to add each line into a array for loading them later.

**Code in JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById('file').onchange = function(){

  var file = this.files[0];

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(progressEvent){
    // By lines
    var lines = this.result.split('\n');
    arr
    for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
      console.log(lines[line]);
    }
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
};
```

**Code in HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

 <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
 <script type="text/javascript" src= "Functions.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE 2**

I think I have added the names into an array (ImageNameList), still I am having trouble with displaying all the images. Here is what I have so far:

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById('file').onchange = function(){

    var file = this.files[0];

    var ImageNameList = [];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(progressEvent){
    // By lines
    var lines = this.result.split('\n');

    for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
        console.log(lines[line]);
        ImageNameList.push(lines[line]);
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = ImageNameList;
    }
};
reader.readAsText(file);
};

function displayAllImages() {
    var i = 0,
        len = ImageNameList.length;        
    for (; i < ImageNameList.length; i++) {

        var img = new Image();
        img.url = ImageNameList[i];
        img.style.width = '160px';
        img.style.height = '120px';

        document.getElementById('images').appendChild(img);
    }
};
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

 <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
<div id="test"></div>

<div id="container">

    <div class="ImageNameList">
        <ul id="images"></ul>
    </div>
</div>

 <script type="text/javascript" src= "Functions.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A little code never killed nobody. Please take a look at how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) example.

Comment: You can use `push()` to push items into an array.  Please take a look at this as I think it will help you. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: Ben, please don't edit your question once someone explains how to do something. This is changing the question meaning an existing answer posted will look incorrect. Your question is how to put the results into an array from your existing `for()` loop. I have explained you can use `push()` and included the relevant link for resources. I don't know why you have now added it to your question source code. To display those images you need to iterate through the array. I suggest you research basic javascript and arrays.

Comment: I apologize @NewToJS, I'm quite new to stackoverflow and web programming. I will look up some javascript references online for displaying the images as you haved suggested. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you change from a txt file to a json file so that the client can parse it.

```
{
  "filenames": ["1.jpg", "2.jpg"]
}
```

Then you can load the json file with a xhr request and parse the response body with JSON.parse.

Hope this helps. I can give a more complete example when not on the phone if needed.

Comment: This is more of a recommendation and should be placed in the comments. This doesn't answer or solve the question above.

Comment: A complete example would be nice if possible! Thanks in advance :)